# How to hide image if screen size is less than 480px (iPhone 4)?

Tags: html, css, iphone, image, size

I have a popup image that shows up on our homepage, But i want to hide it if a viewer is visiting our website from a mobile device (such as an iPhone 4), simply because the image is to big for the phone, without having to zoom out. Here is my code:

```
<div class="gamedayad">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

    <script>
      function openColorBox(){
        $.colorbox({href: "image url"});
      }

      function countDown(){
        seconds--
        $("#seconds").text(seconds);
        if (seconds === 0){
          openColorBox();
          clearInterval(i);
        }
      }

      var seconds = 5,
          i = setInterval(countDown, 0);
    </script>
</div>
```

and the CSS i have (idk if it is correct) is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .gamedayad {
        display: hidden !important;
    }
}
```

Please help? Thanks!

Comment: For a complete question, briefly describe what goes wrong with the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct CSS markup is:

```
display: none !important;
```

However bear in mind you are still downloading the image in a mobile device, and hiding it. The best approach would be to only download the image if you can display it. A simple check to the window width in your script would do the trick.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

if (windowWidth > 480) {
    //download your image here
}
```

Comment: @HunterMiller try this, css may not be enough

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .gamedayad {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark my answer correct if you choose to. Check the check-mark.

Comment: I tried that in the beginning, but it is still showing up on my mobile device.

Comment: make sure you add this in the head of your html page:
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 1):

`display: hidden;` doesn't exist, it must be `display: none;`

Your media query is correct, just the wrong property value is all :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the property "display" and the value "hidden". Try `display: none;`:

```
.gamedayad {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i think what my problem was that I didn't have this script at the top of the page, it was posted at the bottom (under other scripts). I did however put in the:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

if (windowWidth > 480) {
    //download your image here
}
```

posted by denisol, and:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .gamedayad {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone for the help!!